# Hiding id with RESTful routes - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've added a resource route to my app using -

```
resources :cars
```

I've used scaffolding to do this

I've then changed the routes so the user can edit a car by using the following url - mydomain.com/CARNAME

```
match "/:car" =>"cars#edit", :as => :edit_car
match "/:car/thanks" =>"cars#thanks", :as => :thanks
```

My edit action looks like this -

```
def edit
  @car = Car.find_by_name(params[:car]) || not_found
end
```

**My problem is that in the edit page (mydomain.com/CARNAME) renders a form like this -**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/cars/2" class="edit_car" id="edit_car_2" method="post">
```

**I want to hide the ID of the car I'd prefer it to look like this -**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/cars/CARNAME" class="edit_car" id="edit_car_CARNAME" method="post">
```

My update action is like this at the moment -

```
def update
  @car = Car.find(params[:id]) #I'll have to change this to - Car.find_by_name(params[:name])
  if @car.update_attributes(params[:car])
      format.html { redirect_to(thanks_path(@car.name)) }
   else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
   end
end
```

I'd also like the update action to redirect back to the edit action (mydomain.com/CARNAME) and continue to pass through any validation issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding the method `to_param` in your Car model:

```
class Car
  def to_param
    self.name
  end
end
```

The view should then render the url you're expecting.

Comment: This caused me a whole world of pain on deployment to Heroku. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386403/heroku-error-nomethoderror-undefined-method-updated

Comment: For this to work your `to_param` has to include the object id. Such as `"#{self.id}-#{self.name}"`  - if you just want the name u better off using friendly id to keep the mapping between them: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: apart from that I can't really see anything wrong with your code. And I actually use Friendly id in prod on Heroku. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something more versatile than just overriding `to_param`, you could use [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.